# Adding elements to a binary search tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

can comeone please help me. Im trying to add elements to a binary search tree but it doesnt work. It seems like its only adding the first number as the root element and then its not adding anything anymore. Here is the code.

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 1;
    int v, b, c;
    TNode1 j = new TNode1(0, null, null);
    BST1 s = new BST1();

    while (a == 1) {
        System.out.println("1.Add numeber\n2.Print\n3.Stop");
        v = kb.nextInt();

        switch (v) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Give a number");
            b = kb.nextInt();
            s.insert(b);
            break;

        case 2:
            s.Print();
            break;

        case 3:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In BST1 class:

```
public void insert(int x) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new TNode1(x, null, null);
        lastFound = root;
    } else {
        lastFound = root.insert(x);
    }
}
```

In TNode class:

```
protected int element;
protected TNode1 left;
protected TNode1 right;

public TNode1 insert(int x) {
    if (x < element) {
        if (left == null) {
            left = new TNode1(x, null, null);
            return left;
        } else
            return left.insert(x);
    } else if (x > element) {
        if (right == null) {
            right = new TNode1(x, null, null);
            return right;
        } else
            return right.insert(x);
    } else
        return this;
}
```

Here are the print methods:

In BST1 class:

```
public void Print() 
{
        root.Print();
        System.out.println(".");
}
```

In TNode1 class:

```
public void Print() 
{
        System.out.print("(");
        if (left != null) 
        {
            left.Print();
            System.out.print(this);
        }
        if (right != null) 
        {
            right.Print();
            System.out.print(")");
        }
}
```

Comment: On the first note, If `BST1` is wrapper class around `TNode1` then, the `insert(int x)` should be implemented in `BST1` class not in `TNode1`. Also, `BST` and `Node` seems good choice of names to me

Comment: I have not tried it, but it looks like working fine. How did you come to know it is not adding anything anymore? Is your `Print()` method correctly implemented? Can you show the `Print()` method too ?!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the print methods to the original post. @AnandUndavia

Comment: This seems something non standard traversing of tree. Have you tried `inorder` traversal ?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer where I explained what is wrong with your Print method.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that stop will not stop the cycle. In case of stop, you need to set `a = 1;`

It is good to call `s.insert`, which will create the `root` if it didn't exist and call `root.insert(x)` otherwise.

The `insert` for `TNode` seems to be right. The possible problem you might have is with the `print` method. Suggestion:

```
public void print(String path, TNode1 node) {
    System.out.println(path + ": " + node.getElement());
    if (node.hasLeft()) print(path + "L", node.getLeft());
    if (node.hasRight()) print(path + "R", node.getRight());
}
```

Note that I have used a lot of helper methods here. If you do not have them, then you will need to implement them. You can call print like this:

```
s.print("", s.getRoot());
```

EDIT:

After the question has been edited, we have more information about the `print` method. This is the code:

```
public void Print() 
{
        System.out.print("(");
        if (left != null) 
        {
            left.Print();
            System.out.print(this);
        }
        if (right != null) 
        {
            right.Print();
            System.out.print(")");
        }
}
```

Problems:

- Instead of `System.out.print(this)` you need `System.out.print(this.getElement())` to `print` the `int` instead of `this`
- At the right-hand-side you do not `print` the element, please take a look at my `print` above, it should inspire you